# Facebook Album fetcher

Tags: 7

I am using [facebook album fetcher](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_album_fetcher) module. It shows an error message

> An unknown error occurred while trying to fetch the album (empty reply).

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the module [Facebook Album Fetcher](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_album_fetcher) has already posted a reply to a [similar/identical problem](https://drupal.org/node/1919942) that was posted in [drupal.org](https://drupal.org). The general idea is that if you have followed the 10 steps that are described in the module page, you should log in to your facebook account and make sure that the album that you are trying to fetch is actually public.

Comment: my fb album is set to public already. still not working

Comment: Did you follow the 10 steps that are described in the module's page to the letter? For example, did you get the proper access token and saved it (STEP 4) after you have connected your facebook account with Facebook Album Fetcher?

Comment: yeah.. i followed all steps. i am working on local m/c

Comment: I assume that you are working on a virtual machine and that you made sure that it has internet access. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to fetch the album (and it would give you the error message that you are getting). The specific module can give 4 different error messages: 1) if there is a problem with the oAuth Token, 2) if there is a problem with the album id's existence, 3) if there is an issue with the album id's access and there is a 4th error message (the one that you are actually getting) that is the default for every other possible error, so it does not describe the problem accurately

Comment: i agree with you. but i am using internet that why i am able to post here too.

Comment: it isn't self explaining that your virtual machine has also Internet access when you have Internet access on your host machine.